# How to create Appengine Datastore Cursor instance for testing?

Tags: google-app-engine, unit-testing, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing a unit test for some code that contains a `Cursor` from App Engine's datastore.

How do I create a new `Cursor` instance?

---

Here's what I tried:

```
Cursor.fromWebSafeString("some string ..")
```

This fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to decode provided cursor.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursor.fromWebSafeString() is the completion of a round trip from

String encodedCursor = original.toWebSafeString();

Its intended to be used for passing cursors back and forward between client and server.

Cursors are created via factory from a prepared query.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Cursor

Comment: So you're saying I need to make a query to get a Cursor for unit testing?

Comment: A cursor with out a query makes no sense.  So yes.